# How to setup Amazon EC2 Security Group for ionic source?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, amazon-ec2

I am working on an ionic app that uses node.js rest api hosted on amazon ec2. While setting up the the windows server on ec2 we get Step 6: Configure Security Group where we need to mention source ip addresses alowed but in my case what will be the ip address as it is an ionic app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a phone app then you probably will want to open the security group to all traffic instead of specifying an IP address. Then you will want to use some sort of authentication method to ensure only your app can use the API.

Comment: Thanks for answering mark...can you please provide some example of authentication method to ensure this as i cannot find any